# na.fill in Spark DataFrame Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using Spark/Scala and I want to fill the nulls in my DataFrame with default values based on the type of the columns.

i.e String Columns -> "string", Numeric Columns -> 111, Boolean Columns -> False etc.

Currently the DF.na.functions API provides na.fill
`fill(valueMap: Map[String, Any])` like

```
df.na.fill(Map(
    "A" -> "unknown",
    "B" -> 1.0
))
```

This requires knowing the column names and also the type of the columns.

OR

```
fill(value: String, cols: Seq[String])
```

This is only String/Double types, not even Boolean.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: You might need to use `isInstanceOf` to check the incoming data type and replace with proper value.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used Pattern Matching to find the type, nad created a map, and used it

Comment: Unfortunately even `Spark v2.2.1` supports only a **limited number of datatypes** for `DataFrame.na.fill` operation. Quoting [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions@fill(valueMap:Map[String,Any]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), `"value must be of the following type: Int, Long, Float, Double, String, Boolean."`

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [`dtypes: Array[(String, String)]`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame). You can use the output of this method to generate a `Map` for `fill`, e.g.:

```
val typeMap = df.dtypes.map(column => 
    column._2 match {
        case "IntegerType" => (column._1 -> 0)
        case "StringType" => (column._1 -> "")
        case "DoubleType" => (column._1 -> 0.0)
    }).toMap
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used Pattern Matching to find the type, nad created a map, and used it

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how did you do this?