# Spark dataframe replace null values for different data types in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Similar question has answers in SO,  but this requirement is little different.
[na.fill in Spark DataFrame Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225528/na-fill-in-spark-dataframe-scala)

I have a  sample dataframe like below. Each column in the dataframe is different data types.
So using `df.na.fill` is not working to replace all the null values.

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| date                    | id                      | name                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2000-01-01              | NULL                    | ABC                     |
| NULL                    | 123                     | NULL                    |
| NULL                    | NULL                    | CDE                     |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

So irrespective of the data type of the column all the NULL should be replaced by empty string. 
The number,and name of the columns in the dataframe will be keep changing.

Based on the input dataframe data type NULLs should be replaced.

Schema of this dataframe:

```
root
 |-- date: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- points_redeemed: string (nullable = false)
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| date                    | id                      | name                    |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2000-01-01              |                         | ABC                     |
|                         | 123                     |                         |
|                         |                         | CDE                     |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Can someone advise ?

Comment: So you need also to change the types of your columns. You must have all the columns as strings...

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, Ok, If I change the data types of all the columns to strings. Does it affect when I save the result dataframe into Hive table ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*Does it affect*"? If you mean will be saved as strings then yes.

Comment: Yes I meant that. When saving the results back to hive it should not change the data types. It should save as source hive.

Comment: But why are trying to do that? A date is either filled or null, why do you want it as empty string?

Comment: If you wish not to change the data types and replace NULLs with empty strings, you are asking for something impossible. Empty string is inherently a string, thus the data type has to be String. You cannot have an integer with value '', that's not an integer. I'd suggest to think about why this is wanted/for what reason, because I'm fairly certain there is a different/possible solution to your real problem.

Comment: @blackbishop, If it stays as NULL, I am having some problems during my further transformations. Also the final result should not have any other default values for this column. Meaning the column can be either NULL or empty.

Comment: @RichardNemeth, If I take the approach of changing the data types of my dataframe and replace NULL with empty string, I think the final dataframe would lost its original data types. But is there a way when I write my results back to the hive table, the result data frame to have the same schema as source data frame.

Comment: @scalauser There are always solutions to handle nulls during transformations. I'd suggest you edit your question and explain what problems you're encountering so that you could get help. Again, saying a date column is empty has no sense, it should be NULL otherwise it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foldLeft` on dataframe columns and check if the value is **`literal NULL or .isNull or length(trim(col)) === 0`** then replace with "" else don't change the value.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val df= Seq(("2000-01-01","NULL","ABC"),("NULL","123","NULL")).
toDF("date","id","name").
withColumn("date",col("date").cast("timestamp")).
withColumn("id",col("id").cast("int"))

df.printSchema
//root
// |-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)
// |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
// |-- name: string (nullable = true)

df.show()

//+--------------------+----+----+
//|                date|  id|name|
//+--------------------+----+----+
//|2000-01-01 00:00:...|null| ABC|
//|                null| 123|NULL|
//+--------------------+----+----+

#using when otherwise to determine NULL value and replacing with "" if matches.
val df2=df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => {
  df.withColumn(s"$c",when((lower(col(s"$c")) === lit("null")) || (col(s"$c").isNull)|| (length(trim(col(s"$c"))) === 0),lit("")).otherwise(col(s"$c")))
})

df2.show()
//+-------------------+---+----+
//|               date| id|name|
//+-------------------+---+----+
//|2000-01-01 00:00:00|   | ABC|
//|                   |123|    |
//+-------------------+---+----+
```

You can also add more checks in when statement if needed!

Comment: Do note that all columns will be of string type after this. The wanted dataframe with different data types and nulls replaced by "" (a string) is not possible to create.